# Always getting timeout error in running python cgi script on apache

Tags: cgi, python-2.7

This is a crawler that prints all the URLs available on a given link.

```
#!C:/Python27/python.exe -u
import urllib
import cgi,cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

def get_page(url):
    try:
        return urllib.urlopen(url).read()
except:
    return ""

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find('<a href=')
    if start_link == -1: 
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

def get_all_links(page):
    links = []
    while True:
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            links.append(url)
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break
    return links

def union(a, b):
    for e in b:
        if e not in a:
            a.append(e)

def add_page_to_index(index, url, content):
    words = content.split()
    for word in words:
        add_to_index(index, word, url)

def add_to_index(index, keyword, url):
    if keyword in index:
        index[keyword].append(url)
    else:
        index[keyword] = [url]

def lookup(index, keyword):
    if keyword in index:
        return index[keyword]
    else:
        return None

def crawl_web(seed): # returns index, graph of inlinks
    tocrawl = [seed]
    crawled = []
    graph = {}  # <url>, [list of pages it links to]
    index = {} 
    while tocrawl: 
        page = tocrawl.pop()
        if page not in crawled:
            content = get_page(page)
            add_page_to_index(index, page, content)
            outlinks = get_all_links(content)
            graph[page] = outlinks
            union(tocrawl, outlinks)
            crawled.append(page)
    return index, graph

index, graph = crawl_web('http://www.bing.com/results.asp?q=fulcrum')

print graph
print """
<html>
<body>
Animesh Pandey
</body>
</html>
"""
print "<br>"
print graph
print "<br>"
print index
print "<br>"
print tocrawl
print "<br>"
print seed
```

This python file runs fine on an online interpreter! At least it gives some result ....
but when running on a browser it always gives a timeout!!
I am using Apache 2.2.11 and Python 2.7.3.

Please tell me what should I try to do ???

Comment: possible: the cgi script output is only passed to the browser when the script terminated. Does your scipt stop and with which output after what time?

Comment: The browser does not output anything .... only keeps loading!
This is error that is given in the Apache error log:
[Fri Aug 10 02:51:18 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Script timed out before returning headers: test.cgi

Comment: It seems like your script cannot crawl all sites within time. Could be if a socket time out once. Does it get better, if you lower the count of crawled hosts? or set `socket.settimeout()`?

Comment: Just in order to check whether the script is running should I just try to crawl a static webpage with some links .... I guess it won't take much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct version of the code.

```
#!C:/Python27/python.exe -u
import urllib
import cgi,cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

def get_page(url):
    try:
        return urllib.urlopen(url).read()
except:
    return ""

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find('<a href=')
    if start_link == -1: 
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

def get_all_links(page):
    links = []
    while True:
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            links.append(url)
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break
    return links

def union(a, b):
    for e in b:
        if e not in a:
            a.append(e)

def add_page_to_index(index, url, content):
    words = content.split()
    for word in words:
        add_to_index(index, word, url)

def add_to_index(index, keyword, url):
    if keyword in index:
        index[keyword].append(url)
    else:
        index[keyword] = [url]

def lookup(index, keyword):
    if keyword in index:
        return index[keyword]
    else:
        return None

def crawl_web(seed): # returns index, graph of inlinks
    tocrawl = [seed]
    crawled = []
    graph = {}  # <url>, [list of pages it links to]
    index = {} 
    while tocrawl: 
        page = tocrawl.pop()
        if page not in crawled:
            content = get_page(page)
            add_page_to_index(index, page, content)
            outlinks = get_all_links(content)
            graph[page] = outlinks
            union(tocrawl, outlinks)
            crawled.append(page)
    return index, graph

theurl = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/86814352/ani.html"
index, graph = crawl_web(theurl)

print "<br>"
print graph
print "<br>"
```

This prints the urls on that static web page but this code is not suitable for sites with many links!